# How to read more than 1 image using highgui(opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv

I am developing a program to display batch of image and make record while clicking the selected position of the image.

I would like to load set of images( named in incremental order)
and open it 1 after the previous one is closed.

What I wanted the program like step by step:
A file with batch of images named in order (including JPEG, TIFF and PNG formats.)
e.g. IMG_00000001.JPG to IMG_00000003.JPG...

When I run my program, it will display the first image (IMG_00000001.JPG)
then I will click the image and the cmd will show the position that I clicked.
After closing the window, the next image will be displayed(IMG_00000002.JPG).
Continue until the last image in the folder.

Thanks a lot !! I have been searching through the internet for the past few weeks, there are examples but get errors every single time while running it, I was so frustrated and desperate for answer!

Here is my code

```
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{
     if  ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
     {
          cout << "Clicked position is:  (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
     }         
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     // Read image from file 
     Mat img = imread("cube_0.JPG");
     Mat img1 = imread("cube_1.JPG");

      //if fail to read the image
     if ( img.empty() ) 
     { 
          cout << "Error loading the image" << endl;
          return -1; 
     }

      //Create a window
     namedWindow("My Window", 1);

      //set the callback function for any mouse event
     setMouseCallback("My Window", CallBackFunc, NULL);

      //show the image
     imshow("My Window", img);

      // Wait until user press some key
     waitKey(0);

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: help plz...................

Comment: help plz.....................

Comment: help[ plz.....................................